# Simple dendrogram

Tags: beamer, trees

I am just trying to create a simple dendrogram in beamer to develop an intuition for heirarchical clustering and I have tried several sites and several tree diagrams but cannot get anything to do what I want it to.  This is the first time I have used latex/beamer and I am struggling.  I want it to start with a standard deck of 52 cards as one group then split into 2 nodes (black and red), then have each of those nodes split into 2 nodes(by suit: so the red side would split to diamonds and hearts and the black side would split into spades and clubs) then have that node split into face cards and numerical cards, and finally have each card be in its own group.I also want to be able to start with all 52 cards in their own group and then group them until I get to a full deck. Is there a way to do this? (And apparently I can't just post a picture of my hand drawn diagram because my reputation isn't high enough so sorry that this isn't more clear)

I think the MWE I am wondering is how to get my tree diagram in a beamer frame? Does something about the tikzpicture make it so that it cannot go into a frame?  Most examples use documents and not frames.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Do you search for something similar to [TikZ examples feature: Trees](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/)?

Comment: I tried the trees examples.  And I actually had gotten one to work but just not in beamer.  My tree would show in the header but when I tried to put it in its own frame it wouldn't compile and it would say the error was one the \end{frame} line

Comment: @user28769 please upload your hand made drawing elsewhere and provide a link here, so we can see what you are after.

Comment: @user28769 Since you said you already have some preliminary code, you could also add it to your question.

Comment: I got it! Sorry, I'm using writelatex online and it apparently had put in a ghost brace to show where I needed one and I kept reading it as if it was there.  I'm really bad at this.  Thank you everyone